# MYSQL IF NULL THEN DISPLAY N/A

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I'm new to MYSQL and I'm trying to display N/A when the return query show null so far this code works

```
 SELECT 
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT userinfo.status SEPARATOR ', ') as 'Type of Learners'
FROM userinfo 
Inner Join daily on  userinfo.id=daily.userid
where
    daily.date_opened >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 0 day)
and daily.survey_at='Bayan'
```

but when I try to add the ifnull statement I receive an error

```
SELECT 
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT userinfo.status SEPARATOR ', ') as 'Type of Learners'
     Case when userinfo.statusy <>  '' then  'N/A' ELSE 'N/A' end
FROM userinfo 
Inner Join daily on  userinfo.id=daily.userid
where
    daily.date_opened >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 0 day)
and daily.survey_at='Bayan'
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Case when userinfo.statusy <>  '' then  'N/A' ELSE 'N/A' end
> FROM userinfo

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Same output for 'Case', is it just for the example?

Comment: Well, that's cause you didn't have a comma before your `CASE` statement. Specifically here `... as 'Type of Learners'
     Case when ....`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ui.status SEPARATOR ', '), 'N/A') as Type_of_Learners
FROM userinfo ui JOIN
     daily d
     ON ui.id = d.userid
WEHRE d.date_opened >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 0 day) AND
      d.survey_at = 'Bayan';
```

Comment: thank you so much i should study more SQL commands I think thank you again bro